# How to get a response from a web service with php and cURL

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am trying to connect to a web service with cURL and PHP. This is my code, along with the form for the user input.:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Sofia');
    $hotelID = 1;
    $userName = 'admin';
    $password = 'admin';
    $url = 'http://serviceurl.com/someservice/freerooms.svc';
    $requestTime = date('d.m.Y H:m:s');
    $tempFromDate = date_create($_POST['fromDate']);
    $tempToDate = date_create($_POST['toDate']);
    $fromDate = date_format($tempFromDate, 'd.m.Y H:m:s' );
    $toDate = date_format($tempToDate, 'd.m.Y H:m:s' );
    $data = array(
        'fromDate' => $fromDate,
        'toDate' => $toDate,
        'hotelID' => $hotelID,
        'requestTime' => $requestTime,
        'userName' => $userName,
    );
    $token = md5(md5($password . $requestTime));

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    echo $token . '<br>';
    echo curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Bearer: ' . $token));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if (!$response) {
        $error = curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    $result = json_decode($response,true);
    print_r($result);

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" style="position: absolute; top: 40%; left: 20%;">
    <div id="form-messages">
        <?php
        if(isset($error)) {
            echo '<b>Error: </b>' . $error;
        } else {
            $error = null;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post" class="form-inline" id="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="date" name="fromDate" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="date" name="toDate" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem is, I don't have access to the service from the back end. All the person that maintains it has told me, is the format of the data that should be submitted, and that the response will be in JSON format. This is for hotel room reservation. I am told that I should submit the data in the headers along with the token. When I submit this code, I get an empty response, with an error, stating that the token is INVALID. It's the first time I've been working with cURL and RESTful services, so any help is welcome.

Comment: I guess this is not about CURL or any mistake in your code but that you have missed the part where you authenticate to the third-party booking service.

Normally in restfull API's you authenticate with a user & password and get a TOKEN in response. You will have to send this token in the authentication header for each HTTP call to the webservice.

Ask the person who manages the backend.

Comment: ok, thanks. I was afraid there was something wrong with my logic or code